# My Citroen DS3 is struggling to start

Tags: electrical, citroen

I have a Citroen DS3 that was running fine until yesterday.

I had an engine warning light come on, the car was still driving fine, then my car wouldn't restart. Before it cut out there was a strange whirring noise after I took the key out.

I managed to start it again with a jump, but did the exact same thing happened when I tried restarting it a few times, but now the engine warning light has gone.

Any ideas?

Comment: First charge the battery properly then retest and check for any codes.

Comment: The warning light is important here.  You'll need a scanner tool to read out the service code which will likely help you determine the issue.  It sure sounds like an electrical problem.  Perhaps a bad battery, alternator, alternator drive belt or a combination of these.